# Control image quality after transform scaling

Tags: javascript, css, rendering

For example:

- there is an 1000x1000 image
- I add style to it `width:10px`
- I add transform style that scales it by 100x: `transform: scale(100, 100)`
- And finally image size becomes 1000px.

The problem:

- I expect the image to be blurred, since it's 100x scaled from 10px. But it's not, the image is full resolution.

**Is there any way to control the quality?** I tried applying to `scale` to parent element, to child element itself, but no matter what I do - image is rendered at the real size.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dpfmp4hz/

Why I need this:

- I need to run scaling animation from 4000x4000 image to 600x600, and scaling down causes significant lag. What's interesting is that scaling from 600x600 to 4000x4000 is very smooth, since I apply 4000x4000 dimensions only after transition is finished.

I really don't want to use canvas...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The only way I can imagine doing that is by grabbing the image pixels from a `<canvas>` and taking out the pixels you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle with a reduction from 4000px down to 600px, I don't see any lag as you describe using the following css:

```
img {
  width: 4000px;
  height: auto;
}
.parent {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent:hover {
  transform: scale(.15, .15);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p5yL6fwo/1/

Is there something further to your issue which I am not seeing? Are you using a device/computer which might struggle repainting such an image transition?

This is the same but transforming up, again no lag:
https://jsfiddle.net/he12r8g5/

Comment: Thanks for help, your last fiddle is very interesting, if I remove "display:inline-block" it starts lagging again, see example https://jsfiddle.net/tL8goweg/ I also forgot to mention that the issue happens in Chrome, do you test in Chrome too? Safari & FF behave a bit differently.

Comment: I checked on Chrome, Safari and Firefox all without lag. If inline-block solves it then the CSS above is correct I guess :)